# What are the possible Mann Manor gifts spawn places?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I've been playing on a couple 24/7 Mann Manor servers (*I know!*) to get some of the ghostchievements and scarechievements I missed from previous years.

I got the pumpkin hat, the paper mask, the haunted scrap and one of the nine class paper hats (the Heavy one). I found the relevant gift in the shack opposite the first point.

What are the other possible gift spawning locations?

Comment: Where are these servers? How long do we have until the Halloween period is over?

Comment: @JuanManuel Simply filter your server browser to the `cp_manor_event` map. As for the time period, I have honestly no idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are quite a few possible locations.  The ones I know of include:

- The shack between BLU spawn and point A (left side from BLU), lower level.
- The shack between BLU spawn and point A (right side from BLU), upper level.
- The little dead-end near point A.
- Right in front of point A.
- On top of the rocky cliff between points A and B.
- The little shack between points A and B.
- Right in front of point B.
- The balcony near point B where RED initially has a drop down to point A.
- The other balcony near point B.
- The upstairs room across from RED's upper spawn door near point C.
- The downstairs room across from RED's lower spawn door near point C.
- The library room inside the Manor (left from RED spawn).
- The little dead-end room near point C.

As you might have guessed, there are a lot of different places it can spawn.  Not only that, but unlike the Horsemann, it appears to have no bearing on which points are actively in play.

Being a Scout gives you an advantage to finding them, since you move faster.

Comment: Any chance of pictures? :3

Answer (score 7):

Here's a map of the possible locations:

[image: Here's a map of the possible locations]

Comment: Nice, but a few possibilities are lacking. I've found two gifts in the buildings opposite point A, which isn't marked at all.