# Where do gifts spawn in Eyeaduct?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Dual to the question for [Mann Manor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33037/what-are-the-possible-mann-manor-gifts-spawn-places), where can gifts spawn in the 2011 Halloween map [Eyeaduct](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Eyeaduct)?  The couple I've found have just been in the middle while fighting for the point, never seen them "behind enemy lines" or the like.

Apparently gifts can spawn in the underworld as well; are they different and do they only spawn when actually accessible (MONOCULUS is alive)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an [image gallery with the gift locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axQKE.jpg) on Eyeaduct.

The gifts that spawn in the underworld give Haunted versions of the same 2011 Halloween items. There's no special difference between Haunted and non-Haunted versions other than the item name and name color (Haunted items are purple, like unusuals).

According to commenters, gifts can always spawn in the underworld or on the main Eyeaduct map. Apparently there is a difference in the "gift has appeared" message between underworld and non-underworld gifts but I have yet to confirm what the difference actually is.

Comment: Actually the underworld ones can spawn at any time, and it becomes a race to see who's the first through the portal once monoculus spawns.

Comment: I can confirm Mr Smooth's comment is true, I've seen it too